# How to redirect to the url in a .URL file in O365 OneDrive through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Let's say I have a .URL file that's visible in the O365 OneDrive Web UI.  Clicking on this file will correctly redirect me to the url in the contents, in this case http://www.bing.com.  Is it possible, from my application using the Microsoft Graph API to ping that .URL file and open the url in a new tab?

I tried to download the file with an ajax call, view the contents, then redirect from there but any request with the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl, webUrl, etc always attempts to download the file and not let me see the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a way via the Graph API to get the destination of a URL file directly. You would need to download the link file, parse the file to find the embedded URL and then redirect the browser to that URL.

You should be able to do all of that in client-side JavaScript. You would download the file via an Ajax request to the download url, and then you can parse the text content of that request to find the URL.

I know it would be ideal to have that information available directly from the API and that work is in our backlog, but right now you’ll need to do more of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I'm getting a CORS error now but I think I should be able to work through that.

Comment: That’s likely because you are passing the authorization header on the download request. Download requests are pre-authenticated and don’t require the authorization header to be set.

Comment: damn, good call.  Sorry for these noob requests but I'm on a tight deadline for some of this functionality.

Comment: hmm, still getting a CORS error when trying to download a .url file, even without the auth header.  I've tried a few different ajax request variations.